# HTML UL LI CSS: How to change the marker to something other than disc, square, circle, or an image?

Tags: html, css

The web is filled with advice & example pages about how to change the UL LI marker from something other than a dot or square or circle. Many of them suggest using a GIF file, which I am not prepared to do.

All of these examples have one thing in common: They don't work in Firefox. I mean, it's extraordinary! Not one of them functions as claimed.

The main suggestion is to use `li:before { content: "(expression)"; };`

This does not work. Neither when places inside `<style> </style>`, nor when placed inside `style=""`.

Can someone please explain method that will bring about a real and
genuine effect of changing the dot/square/circle to something of my
choosing?

For example, let's make it a star character.

Comment: In CSS3 you will be able to simply write `list-style-type: "*"` but AFAIK no browser supports that yet.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, that's great. I hadn't heard that one yet. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Max no problem. It's mentioned in the CSS3 lists spec, but there is a more digestible version of what's to come, by the guy who's actually writing the spec, here: http://www.xanthir.com/blog/b49Z0

Answer (score 3):

I found a very creative way of doing this.
Check out what this developer did with CSS:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/demo/

Under "User interaction" about half way down he made a star icon using CSS.

Is this what you are looking for?

I found, copied, pasted the code snippet for the star icon.
http://jsfiddle.net/jChwE/1/

Answer (score 1):

The [list style type](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/list-style-type) style specification allows for 3 different types of bullet points:

```
li { margin-left: 2em; list-style-type: disc; }
li.square { list-style-type: square; }
li.circle { list-style-type: circle; }

<ul>
    <li>Normal</li>
    <li class="square">Square</li>
    <li class="circle">Circle</li>
</ul>
```

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jChwE/)

They do work in Firefox.

If you need more options, (such as a star) you will need to use something additional, such as a [list-style-image](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/list-style-image).

Answer (score 1):

Please see [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/josh_max/pttwv/) to see the results.

You can use the `:before` attribute, but it needs to be as in the jsfiddle.

```
HTML:

<ul class="test">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>

CSS:

.test { list-style:none; }
.test>li:before { 
    content:"*";
    font:29px/16px Arial; 
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

You can even try using [**@font-face**](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/) to replace `Arial` with a font that will work better.

`:before` [**is supported**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp), but for it to work in IE8 `<!DOCTYPE>` must be defined.

Comment: That doesn't work all that well because the bullets aren't 'outside' the list. See the difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/pttwv/2/